# CSS keyframes to animate div height from bottom to top

Tags: css

I have the following code that animates the grey bar from top to bottom, however I would like the other way around from bottom to top: http://jsfiddle.net/hrcu9e6b/3/

```
<div class="review-type-wrapper-v">
    <div class="review-type-inner"  style="height:82%">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>

@-webkit-keyframes lineV {
    from {
        height: 0;
    }
    to {
        height: 100%;
    }
}

@keyframes lineV {
    from {
        height: 0;
    }
    to {
        height: 100%;
    }
}

.review-type-wrapper-v,
.review-type-wrapper-h{
    border-radius:3px;
    border:1px solid $rating-background-dark;
    overflow: hidden;
    .review-type-inner{
        position: absolute;
        > div{
            background-color: $rating-background-dark;
            //position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            height: 100%;
            //width:100%;
        } 
    }
}


.review-type-wrapper-v{
    position: relative;
    width: 14px;
    height: 60px;
    .review-type-inner{
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        > div{
            -webkit-animation: lineV 3s linear;
            animation: lineV 3s linear;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I only see a red box which doesn't move when I open the JS Fiddle. Is that correct?

Comment: correct, I was trying to play around...

Comment: You could try positioning the element that animates at the bottom of it's container. The container should have `position:relative;` and the element with the animation should have `position:absolute; bottom:0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a CSS3 2D transform. This only supports IE 10 and above. But, I don't think you care about IE 9 and below because you're using key-frames.

```css
    @-webkit-keyframes lineV {
        from {
            height: 0;
        }
        to {
            height: 100%;
        }
    }
    @keyframes lineV {
        from {
            height: 0;
        }
        to {
            height: 100%;
        }
    }
    .review-type-wrapper-v, .review-type-wrapper-h {
        border-radius:3px;
        border:1px solid #333;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .review-type-inner {
        position: absolute;
    }
    .review-type-inner > div {
        background-color: #333;
        //position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        height: 100%;
        //width:100%;
    }
    .review-type-wrapper-v {
        position: relative;
        width: 14px;
        height: 60px;
    }
    .review-type-inner {
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg); /* Safari */
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    .review-type-inner > div {
        -webkit-animation: lineV 3s linear;
        animation: lineV 3s linear;
    }
```

```html
<div class="review-type-wrapper-v">
    <div class="review-type-inner" style="height:82%">
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```